# Cross Language Variables - Implementation

Tags: php, javascript

Certain Variables I use acrross Javascript and PHP, for example JSON_ON.

I need it set to either 1 on both sides or 0 on both sides...this sets encoding and decoding of structured data.

One way I could implment this is to just have PHP open up the .js file and read the variable.

Is this done?  Are there better ways to implement variables across languages?

I only want to have to set the variable in one place, in this case the .js File.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I think I understand you need to set a constant somewhere? And you need to have both your **JS** and **PHP** to be aware of it? I would personally just do it as a PHP config item and then echo the output to the JS file, OR set the `var item = value` at run of your php script.

Comment: How do I echo the ouptut to the JS file..the only place I do anything like that is in Ajax..but I don't want to have to run Ajax to set my constants..perhaps I misunderstood?

Comment: @downvoters_are_sissies: Your PHP outputs HTML, right? So I guess just having it output the HTML code `<script type="text/javascript">var item = value</script>` close to the beginning of your HTML should be sufficient.

Comment: yeah @celtschk is right, you just put it anywhere on your HTML output (define the VAR in JS, from PHP). You are keeping the var IN php, but just 'defining' it for JS use. No need to do any AJAX or anything fancy.

Comment: easier then opening a js file and reading it form there...this is better.